# eclipse + FindBugs: possible to trigger on SVN synchronize?

Tags: eclipse, svn, findbugs

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 and FindBugs 2.0.1 and synchronize my code with an SVN repository.

Is it possible to trigger FindBugs from eclipse to find bugs on the list of "outgoing changes"-files whenever I synchronize with the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, especially if you want the FindBugs results to be displayed nicely in the Eclipse GUI like when you run it through the FindBugs Eclipse plugin. If you want to do this as requested, some development will probably be required.

Commit-time execution of FindBugs is not available out-of-the-box from FindBugs, the FindBugs Eclipse plugin, the Subversive Eclipse plugin, or the Subclipse Eclipse plugin. TortoiseSVN does support pre-commit actions that could run FindBugs, but it doesn't run in Eclipse and the FindBugs results would need to be imported back into the FindBugs Eclipse plugin somehow. Some people who use SVN from the command line write wrapper scripts for the svn client to perform checks before committing, but that doesn't solve the problem in Eclipse very nicely because we can't easily control what executable Subversive or Subclipse uses.

The closest solution to what you are asking for:
The Subversive Eclipse plugin provides an [extension point](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/extensions.php) for adding commit hooks, but it is not a trivial task to implement one. In addition, if you want the Eclipse integration for your FindBugs results, you will probably need to make the Subversive extension an Eclipse plugin as well so that you can trigger the FindBugs Eclipse plugin (instead of FindBugs itself directly).  Your profile indicates that you might be comfortable enough with Java and Eclipse to try this (and maybe share it with the FindBugs and Subversive communities) but it does look like it would require significant maintenance as the tools evolve, so I hesitate to recommend this solution.

Other options:
Dependencies that can be thought of as pre-commit actions are often best left to a tool designed for managing dependencies such as Maven or Ant (or a zillion other good ones). In addition, waiting until commit time to perform/enforce checks of this kind may not be the best idea, because it can result in discovering problems at the last moment instead of earlier in the build cycle. Who wants to have their last commit of the day blocked, when the FindBugs results can be available as early as compilation time? If you use Ant, I'd suggest adding [the FindBugs ant task](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) to your build process; with a little Ant-fu the class parameter of the FindBugs ant task could be used to limit the checks to items that have changed from the Subversion repository.

If you don't really need the code feedback from FindBugs early (or you already have it in your build) and you really just need an enforcement mechanism, I'd suggest a continuous integration server such as Jenkins (jenkins-ci.org) to test all checked-in code for compliance. Jenkins integrates nicely with Subversion, it can enforce the checking of all new files or the enforcement can be limited to a subteam or subsystem if desired, it can let you know when a violation occurs, and it has the added benefit of not blocking a person from committing code at inconvenient times.

Comment: This seems to be quite more work than I have thought it would be. In fact, at the moment this is quite a bit too much work, at least for me. It was just thought of as a convenient method of using FindBugs, but it would probably be inconvenient to implement this :) But thank you very much for the answer, which is very good, and would very likely be helpful in solving this problem, if I had time to try!